# Amending foreign key on a Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

In Laravel (v5.7.12), I have two models - `User` and `Project`.

A user has an `id` and can have many projects. A project has an `owner_id`.

I can't seem to configure the relationship correctly. In my user model, I have:

```
/**
 * Get the projects associated with the user.
 */
public function projects()
{
    $this->hasMany('\App\Project', 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

In my project model, I have:

```
/**
 * Get the owner associated with the user.
 */
public function owner()
{
    $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'id', 'owner_id');
}
```

But calling either `$user->projects()` or `$project->owner()` returns `null`.

How should I configure my non-standard relationship keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to **return** the method:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Project', 'owner_id');
}
```

Do this also for the second one:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'owner_id');
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaarrrrgh. I must have done this successfully dozens of times! Thank you for your help!